# UDP Packet loss when sending possible?

Tags: java, networking, udp

My professor gave me the task to realize a file transfer via UDP, which implements the protection mechanisms for reliability like as TCP (CRC check, correct packet order, ACK/NACK). I got some default classes from him (Socket & Channel) to simulate packet loss and delay on local machine. A packet loss when sending the packets is also simulated in its classes. However, this means that if an ACK is not sent correctly i can't notice it either, since an ACK from server to client is not confirmed with an ACK for an ACK from client to server.
I thought that packet loss can only happen when receiving packets.
Is it possible in real cases that an packet can be lost while sending without getting a code exception?

Greetings

Comment: `Is it possible in real cases that an packet can be lost while sending without getting a code exception?` Yes, very much so.  What you are doing is re-inventing TCP.  This is fine for a class when learning, but what you are learning is that TCP is a lot more complex than it appears at first.  Normally TCP is a wheel that you would never consider re-inventing.

Comment: I think what you are struggling with in your question specifically is called TCP Retransmission Timeout, and it's a real thing: https://www.extrahop.com/company/blog/2016/retransmission-timeouts-rtos-application-performance-degradation/

Comment: And the other is TCP Idle Timeout: you keep trying to get an ACK or other message from the other side and it just never sends anything.  Once a sufficient amount of time has passed with no packets from the other side the connection can be deleted and an error passed to the calling application.  I recall idle being 45 seconds but this site says it defaults to 300 seconds: https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K13004262

Comment: *IIs it possible in real cases that an packet can be lost while sending without getting a code exception?*  Yes. If what you send is corrupted in transit across any link in the network, then it's not going to be received by the remote UDP, so there's no-one to tell you anything. Think of a datagram as like a postcard written on very thin paper  :-)

Comment: @markspace thanks for your explanations! I have now made it, that the client sends the packet again if it doesn't receive an ack in a given time. in my opinion this is very inefficient, since the server already got the correct data, only that ack did not arrive. Anyways i hope my prof is satisfied

Comment: You cannot **know** whether the server got the correct data or that you failed to get the acknowledgement.  The only way you'd be able to know that is if you could communicate with the server, but you're in a situation where you've failed to communicate with the server.  Sure, maybe you could invent a new message 'did you get my previous message #N', but (a) if the answer is 'no', you need to retransmit, and the extra round-trip was wasted, and (b) that message or its reply can get lost....

Comment: You do however need to make sure that if the server gets the same message more than once, that it is harmless.  Either detect and discard the duplicate, or else have all messages designed such that duplication is harmless.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible in real cases that an packet can be lost while sending without getting a code exception?

Easy. Simply send the packets from your application faster than the network interface can forward these. Of course any intermediate systems on the way (i.e. switches, routers) might also get overloaded and loose packets.

But at the end it does not actually matter how the packet is lost, i.e. if one the local system while sending, on the remote system while receiving or in between while forwarding. One simply cannot assume that a successful `send` will be matched by a successful `recv`.

Answer (score 0):

IP packets contain the transport protocol (TCP, UDP, etc.) in their payload, and you lose IP packets all the time due to things like oversubscription at some point in the path. QoS, controls can also use something like RED that purposely discards packets in order to keep queues from filling and doing tail-drop. TCP can realize that TCP segments (not packets) are lost and resend them, but UDP has no mechanism to realize that its datagrams (not packets) are lost. UDP is a fire-and-forget protocol.